# How to join to one table, and fallback to another?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

i want to join **`Informants`** table to their corresponding **`Handlers`**:

```
 Informants                       Handlers
+------------------------+      +----------------------------------------+
|Name         Type       |      | HandlerID  Name            HandlerType |
|------------ ---------- |      |----------  ----------------------------|
|Ronald Regan Politician |      | 1          J. Edgar        FBI         |
|Sal Vitale   MOB        |      | 2          Charles Cabell  CIA         |
|Elia Kazan   Famous     |      | 3          Allen Dulles    CIA         |
|Mrs. Kravitz Citizen    |      | 7          Joe McCarthy    Congressman |
|White Pawn   Foreign    |      +----------------------------------------+
+------------------------+
```

i follow the rules that depending on who determines the set of people you can inform to:

- Politicians --> CIA
- Mobsters, and famous notables --> the FBI
- ordinary Citizens --> local police department
- Foreign agents --> can turn to the NSA

So i match up **Informers** with who they can **Inform** to:

```
SELECT 
   Informants.Name AS RatName,
   Informants.Type AS RatType,
   Handlers.Name AS GmanName,
   Handlers.HandlerID 
FROM Informants
   LEFT JOIN Handlers
   ON (
      (Informants.Type IN ('Politician') AND Handlers.HandlerType = 'CIA')
      OR  
      (Informants.Type IN ('MOB', 'Famous') AND Handlers.HandlerType = 'FBI')
      OR
      (Informants.Type IN ('Citizen') AND Handlers.HandlerType = 'Police')
      OR
      (Informants.Type IN ('Foreign') AND Handlers.HandlerType = 'NSA')
 )
```

And i get the results:

```
RatName           RatType               GmanName        HandlerID
=============     ==============        ==============  =========
Ronald Regan      Politician            Charles Cabell  2
Ronald Regan      Politician            Allen Dulles    3
Sal Vitale        MOB                   J. Edgar        1
Elia Kazan        Famous                J. Edgar        1 
Mrs. Kravitz      Citizen               NULL            NULL
White Pawn        Foreign               NULL            NULL
```

You can see here that **Ronald Regan** has *two* configured handlers he can turn to. While:

- Mrs. Kravitz, and
- White Pawn

have *no* handler they can inform to.

So what i want now is a fall-back list of handlers. If you're a `Politician` or a `Foreign` agent, we want you to fallback an **`FBI`** handler. This means that ideally my results set will be:

```
RatName           RatType               GmanName        HandlerID
=============     ==============        ==============  =========
Ronald Regan      Politician            Charles Cabell  2
Ronald Regan      Politician            Allen Dulles    3
Sal Vitale        MOB                   J. Edgar        1
Elia Kazan        Famous                J. Edgar        1 
Mrs. Kravitz      Citizen               NULL            NULL
White Pawn        Foreign               J. Edgar        1
```

That's my question, i need to join on the criteria that [**an *earlier* join didn't match anything**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503709/force-partial-join-order-in-sql-server)

---

### The problem

The problem i'm trying to avoid is:

- primary case joins `Politicians` to `FBI`
- backup case joins `Politicians` to `CIA`

And i end up something like:

```
RatName           RatType               GmanName        HandlerID
=============     ==============        ==============  =========
Ronald Regan      Politician            Charles Cabell  2
Ronald Regan      Politician            Allen Dulles    3
Ronald Regan      Politician            J. Edgar        1
Sal Vitale        MOB                   J. Edgar        1
Elia Kazan        Famous                J. Edgar        1 
Mrs. Kravitz      Citizen               NULL            NULL
White Pawn        Foreign               J. Edgar        1
```

And **Ronald Regan** gets a new *"fallback"* entry, when he already had someone to report to.

Comment: Will you ever require a third option (second fallback) or more?

Comment: @TimLehner No, no third fallback. In the case where an informer has no handler, then certain admin users will see a web-page of people wanting to inform but nobody to inform to. They'll handle those as special cases.

Comment: i fear i've simplified my situation down *too far*, and wasted 3 hours composing the question for nothing. (On the other hand if you give people the more complicated example, [they throw up their hands saying *I don't understand*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503709/force-partial-join-order-in-sql-server) and leave)

Comment: On that note, I've given you an answer _almost_ as long as your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter your join conditions a little:

```
SELECT 
   Informants.Name AS RatName,
   Informants.Type AS RatType,
   Handlers.Name AS GmanName,
   Handlers.HandlerID 
FROM Informants
   LEFT JOIN Handlers
   ON 
    (
      (Informants.Type IN ('Politician') AND (Handlers.HandlerType = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Handlers WHERE HandlerType = 'CIA') THEN 'CIA' ELSE 'FBI' END))
      OR  
      (Informants.Type IN ('MOB', 'Famous') AND Handlers.HandlerType = 'FBI')
      OR
      (Informants.Type IN ('Citizen') AND Handlers.HandlerType = 'Police')
      OR
      (Informants.Type IN ('Foreign') AND (Handlers.HandlerType = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Handlers WHERE HandlerType = 'NSA') THEN 'NSA' ELSE 'FBI' END))
    )
```

Comment: *and you already had politicians mapped to CIA?*: Yeah, that will ruin the question - i changed it to Politicians and Foreign Agents report to **FBI**. The trick is that i don't want `Ronald Regan` to *also* report to the FBI, when he can currently report to the CIA. (i.e. i only to join to the *fallback* case when there's no match in the *primary* case)

Comment: Got it, I updated it to something that should work. May not be better performance than doing 2 left joins though, but it's a little more concise.

Answer (score 4):

A little late, I guess, but I'd recommend:

- Use a normalized schema
- Use lookup tables for Types and reference them
- Use a many-to-many junction table for the fallback rules
- Allow for many fallback options
- Avoid putting logic in the code -- do it in the data

Here is the schema setup script:

```
-- Setup test data
create table InformantTypes (
    Type varchar(20) not null primary key
)
insert into InformantTypes select 'Politician'
insert into InformantTypes select 'MOB'
insert into InformantTypes select 'Famous'
insert into InformantTypes select 'Citizen'
insert into InformantTypes select 'Foreign'

create table HandlerTypes (
    Type varchar(20) not null primary key
)
insert into HandlerTypes select 'FBI'
insert into HandlerTypes select 'CIA'
insert into HandlerTypes select 'Congressman'
insert into HandlerTypes select 'Police'
insert into HandlerTypes select 'NSA'

create table InformantTypesToHandlerTypes (
      InformantType varchar(20) not null references InformantTypes (Type)
    , HandlerType varchar(20) not null references HandlerTypes (Type)
    , Ordinal int not null
)
insert into InformantTypesToHandlerTypes select 'Politician', 'CIA', 1
insert into InformantTypesToHandlerTypes select 'MOB', 'FBI', 1
insert into InformantTypesToHandlerTypes select 'Famous', 'FBI', 1
insert into InformantTypesToHandlerTypes select 'Citizen', 'Police', 1
insert into InformantTypesToHandlerTypes select 'Foreign', 'NSA', 1
insert into InformantTypesToHandlerTypes select 'Politician', 'FBI', 2
insert into InformantTypesToHandlerTypes select 'Foreign', 'FBI', 2

create table Informants (
      Name varchar(50) not null primary key
    , Type varchar(20) not null references InformantTypes (Type)
)
insert into Informants select 'Ronald Regan', 'Politician'
insert into Informants select 'Sal Vitale', 'MOB'
insert into Informants select 'Elia Kazan', 'Famous'
insert into Informants select 'Mrs. Kravitz', 'Citizen'
insert into Informants select 'White Pawn', 'Foreign'

create table Handlers (
      HandlerID int not null primary key
    , Name varchar(50) not null unique
    , HandlerType varchar(20) not null references HandlerTypes (Type)
)
insert into Handlers select 1, 'J. Edgar', 'FBI'
insert into Handlers select 2, 'Charles Cabell', 'CIA'
insert into Handlers select 3, 'Allen Dulles', 'CIA'
insert into Handlers select 7, 'Joe McCarthy', 'Congressman'
```

Here's the actual query (it returns the OP's output precisely):

```
-- Actual Query
;with cte as (
    select RatName, RatType, GmanName, HandlerID, DenseRank
    from (
        select
            i.Name AS RatName,
            i.Type AS RatType,
            h.Name AS GmanName,
            h.HandlerID,
            dense_rank() over (partition by i.Name order by ordinal) as DenseRank
        from Informants i
            join InformantTypesToHandlerTypes tt on i.Type = tt.InformantType
            join Handlers h on tt.HandlerType = h.HandlerType
    ) as a
    where DenseRank = 1 -- This bit keeps Reagan from going to the FBI
)
-- Get informants with their first available handler option
select RatName, RatType, GmanName, HandlerID
from cte
-- Get informants with no available handler option
union all
select i.Name, i.Type, null, null
from Informants i
where i.Name not in (select RatName from cte)
order by RatName
```

As a small bit of explanation, here's what this query is doing:

- Just like the OP, we're joining `Informants` to `Handlers` based upon `Type`.  We're just doing it inside of a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) because we want to easily use it multiple times (a CTE is effectively a temporary view, for which a derived table, table variable, or a temp table could just as easily work).
- Rather than join Informants to Handlers based upon hard-coded rules in a complicated switch (that must be maintained should business requirements change), we're doing so based upon a many-to-many junction table that we've created.  Any user can easily change the rules as they see fit now.
- We then add a ranking function to let us know our available primary and fallback Handler options.  We can simply pick the highest-ranked option available per Informant so that we don't needlessly show fallback options that aren't necessary.
- Once we establish this set of data, we can select from it to show all of our Informants with available Handlers.
- It is now simple to get the remaining Informants which have no Handler available by getting (with a union) any Informant not in the CTE.

There are probably other ways to do it, but this is how my thought process worked this time.

Comment: +1 for a very fine answer. On the other hand, my eyes glaze over when i try to understand it :(

Comment: All that SQL is really just a bunch of simple schema setup keeping those 5 bullet points in mind.  The final query is very similar to yours, only joining on `InformantTypesToHandlerTypes` for the fallback info, rather than a complicated switch with hard-coded values that must be maintained.  Happy coding!

Comment: i will admit my brain was never able to grasp CTE's when they were introduced in 2005. And then you throw in rank, dense_rank, parition over, and then a brand new one today "order by ordinal"...  /cry

Comment: How does this query "fallback" to a secondary case (rank `2` in the setup table)? Is that `where DenseRank = 1` ?

Comment: Correct. DenseRank will be 1 for any secondary case when there is no primary case (Handler) available.  Basically, we're looking for the first Handler available as per the Ordinal rules set forth in the junction table.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you add a table to persist the rules as in

```
 InformantRules
Type         PrimRatType SecRatType
Politicians   CIA           CIA 
Mobsters      FBI 
Famous        FBI 
Citizens      Police 
Foreign       NSA           CIA
```

Then you could write

```
Select i.Name, i.Type, 
   Coalesce (p.Name, s.Name) ContactName
From Informants i
   Join InformantRules r On r.Type = i.Type
   Left Join Handlers p on p.HandlerId 
         = (Select Min(HandlerId) 
            From Handlers 
            Where HandlerType = r.PrimRatType)
   Left Join Handlers s on s.HandlerId 
         = (Select Min(HandlerId) 
            From Handlers 
            Where HandlerType = r.SecRatType)
```